# Create a table in a generated PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

How to create a table in a generated `PDF` using `iTextSharp`?

I've have been trying to create a PDF document containing a table dynamically using `iTextSharp`. After search around, I found a few posts which helped me with a basic one. However, I wanted a table with the following structure and I am having a challenge creating it.

[image: Table Structure]

Can someone help?

Comment: Post your code and results of your tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a small Java example to the iText site showing how it's done: [SimpleRowColspan](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/SimpleRowColspan)

As you can see, [the result looks very much like the table you describe](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/simple_rowspan_colspan.pdf). I'm not sure what you mean when you say your searches didn't result in finding an example that helped you. Maybe you're looking for a C# example instead of a Java example? Maybe you found the example that accompanies [the book I wrote](http://itextpdf.com/book), [MyFirstTable](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=75), but didn't find [its C# counterpart](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04).

Although I'm not a C# developer, that would look like this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
float[] widths = new float[] { 1f, 2f, 2f, 2f, 1f };
table.SetWidths(widths);
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("S/N"));
cell.Rowspan = 2;
table.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
table.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Age"));
cell.Rowspan = 2;
table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell("SURNAME");
table.AddCell("FIRST NAME");
table.AddCell("MIDDLE NAME");
table.AddCell("1");
table.AddCell("James");
table.AddCell("Fish");
table.AddCell("Stone");
table.AddCell("17");
```

This should answer your question. If not, please clarify what isn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks, i worked. The approach i used involved creating PdfPRow(s) while configuring it with the cells required; given you would need to have two rows in an HTML table.