# Creating a table like below using itextsharp in a -pdf document

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, itext, html-table

[image]

I am trying to create a pdf document and I am using itextsharp in an asp.net mvc3 application. My pdf document contains address, subject line, some body text. Along with now I want to insert a table like above after the body text. The snapshot of the table is as above: What I would like to do is that I want rowspan (like what one does in html). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you going to parse HTML into PDF or are you manually building an iTextSharp `PdfPTable`? For the former, just `rowspan` in you HTML and you should be fine. For the latter, the `PdfPCell` has a `Rowspan` property. Please post some code if you need more help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a table in a generated PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016630/create-a-table-in-a-generated-pdf)