# Generate table with double column beneath a row

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to create a table such as this with itext: [image]

I tried to followed the solution here: [Create a table in a generated PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016630/create-a-table-in-a-generated-pdf) but unfortunately `M` and `F` column will not go beneath the `Gender` column. Supposedly it should work like in the answer but it is not working. I'm not sure what is wrong. This is my code:

```
document.open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
table.setWidths(new float[]{ 1f, 3f, 1f, 1f, 1f});
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Chapter"));
cell.setRowspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description"));
cell.setRowspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Gender"));
cell.setColspan(1);
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total"));
cell.setRowspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);

table.addCell("M");
table.addCell("F");

document.add(table);
document.close();
```

and this is my current output: 
[image]

Can somebody help me with this?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand it should be:

```
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Gender"));
cell.setColspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);
```

since you want it to be two columns wide.

Comment: Indeed, changing `1` to `2` solved the problem :p Thank you very much for your time.